# how to make a row unique in one to many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

i have the below posted tables. the relation is one to many. single site could has different operations and single operation is to be applied on a single site at a time.
therefore, the primary key of the table `Site` will be a foreign key in the table `operation`. but what i want to have is, the combination between `selectedSiteID`,`treatmentGeometry`,`threshold`,`isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage`,`isVisualizeAverageHeights` in
table `operation` should be unique.in other words, in the table `operation` the values assigned to columns `selectedSiteID`,`treatmentGeometry`,`threshold`,`isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage`,`isVisualizeAverageHeights` should be unique and can not be duplicated.
please let me know how can i achieve that.

**tables**:

```
create table if not exists Site(
selectedSiteID text primary key,
treatmentGeometry geometry,
);
create table if not exists operation(
               threshold smallint,
               isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage boolean,
               isVisualizeAverageHeights boolean,
               primary key (threshold,isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage,isVisualizeAverageHeights)
        );
```

Comment: you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b51a7369835e8b7f2692fc5b98651b93

Comment: btw, you might find this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061966/2275388) interesting. At least I do recall you posting a question on buffers some time ago. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since `selectedSiteID` is a primary on `Site` and a foreign key on `operation` you do not need to repeat `treatmentGeometry` on `operation`. You just the whole record of `operation` unique, just add the foreign key `site_selectedsite_id` to the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Site(
  selectedSiteID text PRIMARY KEY,
  treatmentGeometry geometry
);

CREATE TABLE operation(
  threshold smallint,
  isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage boolean,
  isVisualizeAverageHeights boolean,
  site_selectedsite_id text REFERENCES site(selectedSiteID), 
  PRIMARY KEY (site_selectedsite_id,
               threshold,
               isVisualizeAreaOfCoverage,
               isVisualizeAverageHeights)
);
```

Comment: would you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213305/cascading-update-on-subset-from-composite-foreign-keys